# rs-232 communication parameters is up to us or the device?

Tags: serial-port, embedded, data-export

I have a data sheet for rs-232 device but only baud rate parameter is given in it. Is that mean I can put other parameters (Flow control, parity etc…) as I wish ?

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO. If not specified, it will almost certainly use N,8,1 framing, and no you cannot use any framing or flow control means you wish.  Whether it supports hardware flow control will be implicit on whether it has RTS/CTS lines.

Comment: If the data sheet shows that the only configurable register is baud rate then no you can't set any other parameters because there are no other registers to set.

Comment: Try with parity none, no-flow-control, 1 stop and 1 start bit. You already know the BAUD rate